# Why await does not wait till its completion. I can't get posts results with paginated values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

ViewController.js File

```
const Article = require("../models/articleModel");
    const catchAsync = require("../utils/catchAsync");
    const APIFeatures = require("../utils/apiFeatures");
    
    exports.homePage = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
      let filter = {};
      if (req.params.articleId) {
        filter = { article: req.params.articleId };
      }
      const requestedCategory = new APIFeatures(
        Article.find(filter),
        req.query,
        Article
      )
        .filter()
        .pagination();
      const posts = await requestedCategory.query;
      const { previousPage, nextPage } = requestedCategory;
      console.log(previousPage,nextPage);
      res.status(200).json(posts);
```

ApiFeatures.js
It has many methods one of them is pagination

```
class APIFeatures {
  constructor(query, queryString, Model) {
    this.query = query;
    this.queryString = queryString;
    this.Model = Model;
    this.previousPage = null;
    this.nextPage = null;
  }
  async pagination() {
    let page;
    if (this.queryString.page) {
      page = this.queryString.page * 1;
    } else {
      page = 1;
    }
    const limit = 5;
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;

    if (endIndex < (await this.Model.countDocuments().exec())) {
      console.log("I got printed next page");
      this.nextPage = {
        page: page + 1,
        limit: limit,
      };
    }

    if (startIndex > 0) {
      console.log("I got printed prev page");
      this.previousPage = {
        page: page - 1,
        limit: limit,
      };
    }
    this.query = this.query.skip(startIndex).limit(limit);
    return this;
  }
}
module.exports = APIFeatures;
```

my output it does not wait for paginated result and there is no posts results

```
undefined
undefined
GET / 200 854.131 ms - -
I got printed next page
```

if I removed async/await in apifeatures.js then my output is
I can the posts results but not previousPage and nextPage values
it got executed after the query

```
null
null
GET / 200 1238.407 ms - -
```

Comment: `const posts = await requestedCategory.query;` 
You don't seem to be calling query at all. Shouldn't this be `const posts = await requestedCategory.query();` ?

Comment: @FrankenCode `const post = await requestedCategory.query()` won't work because query comes from class which has chain for queries , in the end it looks like `const post = await requestedCategory.find().sort().limit()`

Comment: Perhaps log the actual content of `requestedCategory` just prior to the `requestedCategory.query` line.

Comment: @Joe I got this  `queryString: {},Model: Model { Article },previousPage: null, nextPage:null`

Comment: Note that there is no `query` there, probably because you didn't await the call to the async function `pagination`

Comment: @Joe but I'm getting json values for posts results

Comment: race conditions are always fun, does it behave differently when you await pagination?

Comment: @Joe where do I await the pagination

Comment: where it is called.

Comment: @Joe but how can I await the pagination in viewcontroller.js

Comment: The same way you await the query

Comment: @Joe `const pagee = await requestedCategory.pagination();` produces same as logging requestedCategory. But I get 5 results as Usual

Comment: Only countDocumets is not working

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).